# How to get ComboboxItem index by Tag?

Tags: c#, wpf

I've the following `Combobox`:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="Colors" FontSize="20">
        <ComboBoxItem Background="#46d6db" Tag="#46d6db">Blue</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem Background="#FDB75B" Tag="#FDB75B">Orange</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem Background="#51B749" Tag="#51B749">Green</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

Now how you can see I've three ComboBoxItems with a specific `Tag` property. The tag property here is the value of the color.

What I need to know is: How can I get the index of a specific ComboBoxItem by the Tag property?

I'll try to explain it more clear possible: Suppose that I've a string called `color` as value `#FDB75B`, now I need to find the ComboBox item with the same `Tag` and take the position of this `ComboBoxItem`, in particular.

```
string color = "#FDB75B";
//In this way I get the Tag property of the selected item
((ComboBoxItem)Colors.SelectedItem).Tag.ToString();
```

Now I need to do the opposite situation, find the `ComboBoxItem` index with the tag `#FDB75B`, and select it automatically, as:

```
Colors.SelectedIndex = "element found";
```

Is this possible?

Comment: using a for loop - loop through each combobox item and get the tag and check it against what you are looking for.  There is no native way to say this tag belongs to this combobox without putting a reference in the tag property (Object) to the index of the combobox.  You could always use a struct with two fields, color and index and use that in the tag property.

Comment: The answer given by Chris shows how you should actually do it. Besides that it's less code, it would also work with other item types, not only ComboBoxItem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use linq query and find out. Here is one sample code

```
var selectedItem = Colors.Items
  .Cast<ComboBoxItem>()
  .Where(e => e.Tag.ToString() == "#FDB75B")
  .FirstOrDefault();

Colors.SelectedItem = selectedItem;
```

Comment: Wow I love the one line solution, thanks seems working well :)

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate through the collection and select like this:

```
string tagColor = "#51B749";
int foundIndex = -1;
foreach (ComboBoxItem item in Colors.Items)
{
    if (item.Tag.ToString() == tagColor)
    {
        foundIndex = item.TabIndex;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are just wanting to select the item programatically, you can set the `SelectedValuePath` and work with it that way. This is my test XAML:

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
     <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
     <RowDefinition Height="*" />
     <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <ComboBox x:Name="Colors" FontSize="20" Grid.Row="0" SelectedValuePath="Tag">
     <ComboBoxItem Background="#46d6db" Tag="#46d6db">Blue</ComboBoxItem>
     <ComboBoxItem Background="#FDB75B" Tag="#FDB75B">Orange</ComboBoxItem>
     <ComboBoxItem Background="#51B749" Tag="#51B749">Green</ComboBoxItem>
  </ComboBox>
  <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="2">
     <Button x:Name="ButtonSet" Click="ButtonSet_Click" Content="Set Selection" />
     <Button x:Name="ButtonDisplay" Click="ButtonDisplay_Click" Content="Display" />
  </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

For `ButtonSet`, it's simply: `Colors.SelectedValue = "#FDB75B";`

For `ButtonDisplay`, it's: `MessageBox.Show("Selected: " + Colors.SelectedValue);`